# graphql, nesjs and prisma api response solution need

Tags: json, typescript, graphql, nestjs, prisma

i use nestjs, graphQL and prisma module to create my endpoint and web service ;

i am looking for way to create custom response in graphQL my endpoint is simple

select books from database my response is

```
{
  "data": {
    "books": [
      {
        "id": "5b5c02beab8dc1182b2e0a03",
        "name": "dasta"
      },
      {
        "id": "5b5c02c0ab8dc1182b2e0a04",
        "name": "dasta"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but in need something like this

```
{
  "result": "success",
  "msg" : "list ...",
  "data": [
      {
        "id": "5b5c02beab8dc1182b2e0a03",
        "name": "dasta"
      },
      {
        "id": "5b5c02c0ab8dc1182b2e0a04",
        "name": "dasta"
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The shape of the response and the query are closely linked in GraphQL. This is defined in the GraphQL specification. Also, every GraphQL response has a `data` and an `error` property at the top level. There is no way to change that. What you re asking is simply not possible. If you want to specify one specific response shape on the server, GraphQL might be the wrong technology; consider REST.
If you provide more information on *why* you need that shape, we might find a different solution together :)

Comment: if you are using graphql only for the purpose of reducing dataset & nothing else.. then I would recommend you to checkout - https://github.com/restmap/restmap-node